# Floated div to begin below another full width floated div

Tags: css, html

I have two columns, in the left column I have made the `.title` extend the full width of the screen using negative margins.
On the right column I have `.sidebar` I would like this to appear below the extented `.title` div. Run the code snippet below and you'll see it starts on the same line. In other words I want the orange div to fall below the yellow div.

I don't want to use `margin-top` on the `.sidebar` because the height of `.title` in the left column varies.

I realise this is possible with javascript but I'm looking for a more robust solution just using html and css, is this possible?

I also created a fiddle if that's more convenient http://jsfiddle.net/2dLaw17r/1/

```css
.container {
    width:600px;
    margin:0 auto;
    clear:both;
    padding:1em;
    background:grey;    
}
.left {
    float:left;
    width:60%;
}

.left .title {
    margin:0 -500%;
    padding:0 500%;
    background: yellow;
}

.right{
    float:right;
    width:40%;
    background:orange;   
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="container clearfix">
    <div class="left">
      <article>            
         <div class="title">Title extends beyond container</div>
        <p>lorem ipsum someip orlem lorem ipsum someip orlem lorem ipsum someip orlem</p>
      <article>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <div class="sidebar">items in this sidebar div should fall below the title div. Currently it starts on the same line.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a design problem, your title just shouldn't be in your left column if you don't want it to be limited to it.

Comment: I want the text in the `.title` to be limited to the left column but the the actual div itself extend beyond. I am using a background image on this div and want it to be the full width of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place a div inside the article that contains the article content. This way the title and content both remain inside the article. Next, float the article content left and the sidebar towards the right. The negative margin trick is no longer required:

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  clear: both;
  padding: 1em;
  background: grey;
}
.title {
  background: yellow;
  /* eye candy only */
  margin: 0 -1em;
  padding: 0 1em;
}
.left {
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
}
.right {
  float: right;
  width: 40%;
  background: orange;
}
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="container clearfix">
  <article>
    <div class="title">Title extends beyond container<br>And can grow in height</div>
    <div class="content left">
      <p>lorem ipsum someip orlem lorem ipsum someip orlem lorem ipsum someip orlem</p>
    </div>
  </article>
  <div class="sidebar right">
    <p>items in this sidebar div should fall below the title div. Currently it starts on the same line.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with your design and not CSS...if you plan your layout carefully you can avoid those *negative margins* altogether.Possible solution is suggested from my side is as below :

Redesign your markup and rename *classes* in more helpful manner :

[working fiddle with updated markup](http://jsfiddle.net/2dLaw17r/5/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="container clearfix">
    <div class="left">
        <div class="title">Title extends beyond container</div>
        <div class="right">
            <div class="sidebar">items in this sidebar div should fall below the title div. Currently it starts on the same line.</div>
        </div>
        <p>lorem ipsum someip orlem lorem ipsum someip orlem lorem ipsum someip orlem</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body { /* always mention this in you CSS - rule of Thumb for CSS */
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}
.container {
    width:100%; /* stretch div to take full width of parent - HTML, BODY*/
    margin:0 auto;
    clear:both;
    padding:1em;
    background:grey;
}
.left {
    /* float:left;*/ /* not needed with updated layout :) */
    width:100%;
}
.left .title {
    /*margin:0 -500%;  
    padding:0 500%;  /* nightmare is removed */ */
    width:100%;
    background: yellow;
}
.right {
    float:right;
    width:40%;
    background:orange;
}
.clearfix:after {
    content:"";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: The biggest problem here is that, in terms of HTML source order,  the title is no longer close to the text it is representing (the lipsum paragraph).

Comment: @SalmanA : are you pointing towards `lorem ipsum someip orlem ...` text?

Comment: yes, rearranging elements is proper solution as long as you do not stray away from original source order.

Comment: I need the sidebar to come after the main content, this content actually lies in `<article>`. The reason I have been asked to do this is from an aesthetic point of view. Eg look here the orange div extents the fullwidth of the page http://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2014/nov/05/my-daughter-my-beautiful-failure

Comment: @SalmanA : if you check the original code from OP..it also has same spacing...so i kept it that way - *its easy to tune up CSS to fix this* . Plus i rearranged assuming that in original source code, of which this snippet is part of, my layout would result in less number of fixes! :)

Comment: @stemie : you want orange `div` to stay fix at 40% width to right and come after main content..[**like this**](http://jsfiddle.net/2dLaw17r/11/)??

Answer (score 0):

Like Antoine says, you have to put the title, outside the left div.

```css
.container {
    width:600px;
    margin:0 auto;
    clear:both;
    padding:1em;
    background:grey;    
}
.left {
    float:left;
    width:60%;
}

.title {
    
    background: yellow;
}

.right{
    float:right;
    width:40%;
    background:orange;   
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="container clearfix">
    <div class="title">Title extends beyond container</div>
    <div class="left">
        
        <p>lorem ipsum someip orlem lorem ipsum someip orlem lorem ipsum someip orlem</p>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <div class="sidebar">items in this sidebar div should fall below the title div. Currently it starts on the same line.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I updated the question slightly I cannot put the `.title` above the `<article>` cause it belongs in there.

Answer (score 0):

You have to clear floats like:

```css
.container {
    width:600px;
    margin:0 auto;
    clear:both;
    padding:1em;
    background:grey;    
}
.left {
    float:left;
    width:60%;
}

.left .title {
    margin:0 -500%;
    padding:0 500%;
    background: yellow;
}

.right{
    float:right;
    width:40%;
    background:orange;   
    clear: left;/*add clear left*/
    margin-top: -60px;/*add negative top margin*/
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="container clearfix">
    <div class="left">
        <div class="title">Title extends beyond container</div>
        <p>lorem ipsum someip orlem lorem ipsum someip orlem lorem ipsum someip orlem</p>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <div class="sidebar">items in this sidebar div should fall below the title div. Currently it starts on the same line.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```